# How to populate select dropdown with numbers from 1 to 10 with each having unique index/value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to add select dropdown with numbers from 1 to 10 with each option having a unique value and default selected option as 1

HTML

```
 <select [(ngModel)]="selectNum">
   <option value=""> </option>
 </select>
```

Comment: why cannot you write 10 options in html file?

Comment: I was wondering if there was a better solution. Like a loop?

Comment: There are plenty of ways to handle this scenario, including the answer that @AugustinR provided.  However, you're much more likely to get positive responses here if you try something, and then ask why what you tried didn't work, rather than just blatantly asking for someone else to write it for you.

Comment: giving an idea like @brk would suffice too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the .ts :

```js
options = [ // id field is not necessary
    {id: 1, value: 'opt1'},
    {id: 2, value: 'opt2'},
    {id: 3, value: 'opt3'},
    {id: 4, value: 'opt4'},
    {id: 5, value: 'opt5'},
    {id: 6, value: 'opt6'},
  ]
```

In the .html :

```html
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let opt of options" [value]="opt.value"> {{opt.value}} </option>
</select>
```

Here is a [stackblitz](https://angular-pjxepe.stackblitz.io)